# The & causes trouble in an array using package versions

Tags: eqnarray

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{versions}

%\excludeversion{teacher}
\includeversion{teacher}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
  a+b&=&c\\
  \begin{teacher}X = \end{teacher}\\
c+d&=&e\\
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works fine, but I like to align `=` nicely.
As soon as I use `\begin{teacher}X &=& \end{teacher}\\`
I get the error:

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.  }  $@eqnsel
> \endtemplate  l.13 \begin{teacher}X &
> =& \end{teacher}\

Comment: you can't start an environment in one alignment cell and close it in another/

Comment: Try with `\begin{teacher}X\end{teacher} &\begin{teacher}=\end{teacher}&\\ `

Comment: Do not overstretch the comment/uncomment stuff. Bite the bullet and repeat the whole equation if you want a teacher and no-teacher version.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That did the trick.

Comment: Never use `eqnarray`.